# Binding OData service to a dropdwon

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to bind data in a dropdown (`sap.m.Select`) from a service but data is not getting displayed in the dropdown. Below is my code:

#### Controller

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("hmel.TravelandGuestHouse.controller.CloneTravelRequest", {
    onInit: function () {
      this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
      //For Train Name
      this.addmodel = new JSONModel();
      this.getView().setModel(this.addmodel, "Model");
      this.actionTemp = this.getView().byId("trainName").clone();
      this.detailModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("detailModel");
      this.getView().setModel(this.detailModel, "detailModel");
      this.router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._handleRouteMatched, this);
    },

    _handleRouteMatched: function(evt) {
      if (evt.getParameter("name") !== "CloneTravelRequest") {
        return;
      }
      var that = this;
      that.getView().byId("trainName").bindAggregation("items", {
        path: "/TravelPrpTrainDetails",
        template: that.actionTemp
      });
    }
  });
});
```

#### View

```xml
<m:Select id="trainName" selectedKey="{detailModel>/TrainName}">
  <core:Item key="{ID}" text="{TrainName}"/>
</m:Select>
```

Data is coming in the below form and I just want to extract `TrainName` attribute from it:

```xml
<entry>
  <id>http://________________________/TravelPrpTrainDetails(36)</id>
  <category
    term="WCFODataService.TravelPropTrainDetails"
    scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
  />
  <link
    rel="edit"
    title="TravelPropTrainDetails"
    href="TravelPrpTrainDetails(36)"
  />
  <title />
  <updated>2019-01-03T06:02:36Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:SerialNo m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:SerialNo>
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">36</d:ID>
      <d:TrainName>AJMER ASR EXPRESS 19611</d:TrainName>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

​Hi Swappy, the solution is pretty simple. Your item's binding should use the same model name of the parent binding. In this case, you should have:

```
<core:Item key="{detailModel>Value}" text="{detailModel>Value}"/>
```

In general, you should always use this rule when your model is not the default one (default is when the model has no name).

```
<ComboBox
    items="{ModelName>/ListOfValues}">
        <core:Item key="{ModelName>Key}" text="{ModelName>Value}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

If you're using the default model you should use this kind of template:

```
<ComboBox
    items="{/ListOfValues}">
        <core:Item key="{Key}" text="{Value}"/>
</ComboBox>
```